# bootstrap-3 - img-responsive not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have built a small site for fun, getting familiar with bootstrap.

The issue I have is that the logo image is not responsive, no matter what I try.

The code seems quite straightforward I am sure I am just missing a minor detail:

```
<div id="masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7 header-logo">
        <div class="header-logo" style="color: white;">
          <img src="/img/gros_buck_175.png"  class="img-responsive"  align="left" style="padding-right: 1.5em;padding-top: 0px; max-width: 184px;">
          <br>
          TEL: 450 955-3422 <br>
          182 CHEMIN D'ADAMSVILLE <br>
          J2L 2Y6, BROMONT<br>
          laboucheriedugrosbuck@gmail.com
          <br clear="all">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="well well-lg">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <img src="/img/sceau_140.png" class="img-responsive" align="left" style="padding-right: 1.2em;">
              <h3 style="margin-top:0px; margin-bottom: 1em;">PROMO</h3>
              FAITES VOTRE PLAN DE VIANDE:<br>
              ACHETEZ POUR PLUS DE 100$ DE PRODUITS
              À L'UNITÉ ET RECEVEZ 10% EN SAUCISSES.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!--/container-->
</div><!--/masthead-->
```

( Here is a fiddle reproducing the issue ) - https://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/2XgDW/2/

Comment: If you are looking for autoresize images depending on the viewport, the way I go is using jquery. As you understand french (like me 'cocorico') just have a look on [example managing images](http://www.debray-jerome.fr/plugin-jquery-responsive-image-15.html)

Answer (score 9):

First remove the `max-width: 184px` attribute from the image tag

```
<img src="/img/gros_buck_175.png"
     class="img-responsive"
     align="left"
     style="padding-right: 1.5em;padding-top: 0px;">
```

Although it would be better to avoid the use of inline styling:

```
<img src="/img/gros_buck_175.png" class="img-responsive" id="myLogo" align="left">
```

```
#myLogo {
    padding-right: 1.5em;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

---

If there is a possibility that one of the ancestor elements' styling may be interfering, you can reset it like so:

```
#myLogo {
    all: initial!important;
    width: 100%!important;
    height: auto!important;
}
```

---

If you're still facing the issue, the next step would be to use JavaScript

```
Object.assign(document.getElementById('myLogo').style, {
    all: 'initial',
    width: '100%',
    height: 'auto'
});
```

This code should be included after the element in the document otherwise it will not be able to find the specified element as it won't exist yet.

---

Now that you've added the example to your question, you can make the image assume its natural size by replacing the following CSS:

```
img {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

With this CSS:

```
img {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/2XgDW/74/))

---

I believe that your use of `display: table` is interfering with your design. Below are two methods of achieving the same layout without hacks.

**CSS3 Method**

All relevant modern browsers support this method so if you dont care about backwards compatibility with old browsers, you can use this method.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/2XgDW/78/))

```
<div class="inline-wrap">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    <div class="text-wrap">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
</div>
```

```
*,*:before,*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.inline-wrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 150px;
}
.inline-wrap img {
    width: 150px;
}
.inline-wrap .text-wrap {
    white-space: initial;
    font-size: initial;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 65%; /* Fallback */
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
}
```

**Table Method**

For backwards compatibility you can use this method.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/2XgDW/76/))

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="img-wrap">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        </td>
        <td class="text-wrap">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
table, tr, td {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table {
    width:100%;
}
table .img-wrap {
    font-size: 0;
}
table .text-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Even without the inline styles image is not responsive and the max-widht, it is not responsive. This directive is left-over from my trial and errors.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/2XgDW/2/ - I made a fiddle of the issue, I am really not sure I have the proper <div> structure,  like maybe the text next to the image does not need to be in a div.

Comment: That is not my original fiddle...  I will repost tomorrow and add a bounty for you

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `max-width` to `width: 100%` that should tell it to take up 100% of the containers width, but as the containers width changes, so will the images size, while always maintaining 100% width coverage.
This SHOULD work, if it doesn't let me know and I'll hack it out a bit.  I'm just on my phone so I don't really want to sandbox it anywhere with a touchscreen keyboard.  If this doesn't work, I'll hack it out on my PC tomorrow afternoon :D!

Ps.  Is there a reason you declare class `.header-logo` in one div and then again in the next div give it the same class.  I understand if it was a different div block, but this is essentially a header logo inside a header logo